# How to make a list of lmer model objects to use in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to write a for loop in R (my first!) in order to produce and save diagnostic plots of several mixed effects models fitted using the function lmer in the package lme4. This is what I've done so far exemplified with the sleepstudy data:

```
require(lme4)

mod1<-lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject),sleepstudy)
mod2<-lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (1|Subject),sleepstudy)

List<-c(mod1,mod2)
names<-c("mod1","mod2")

i=1

for (i in 1:length(List)) {
  jpeg(file = paste("modelval_", names[i], ".jpg", sep=""))
  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  plot(resid(List[i]) ~ fitted(List[i]),main="residual plot")
  abline(h=0)
  qqnorm(resid(List[i]), main="Q-Q plot of residuals")
  qqnorm(ranef(List[i])$Subject$"(Intercept)", main="Q-Q plot of random effect" )
  dev.off()
}
```

I get the following error message when typing into R consol:

```
Error in function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
invalid type (NULL) for variable 'resid(list[i])'
```

I've got a feeling the problem is related to the list of models I've created and not the for loop itself and I think it might be related to the model objects being of class S4. Is it possible to make such a list?
I've also tried to make the list like below, with no improvements (still get the same error message)

```
List<-list(mod1,mod2)
```

Answer (score 2):

First using `c` can risk losing the class structure of the objects you've created. To make a list containing your models, use `list(mod1, mod2)`.

Second, `List[i]` is a list of length 1 containing the i'th element of `List`. Use `List[[i]]` to extract the element itself (your model).